# Error while running two builds at the same time

Tags: linux, makefile, cmake, clearcase-ucm

Does anybody knows why there's an issue while running two builds at the
same time on the same build server?

I have the following error:

```
cp: cannot create regular file
`/tmp/tmpdir_ap/ck/up/config/launcher.11': Permission denied
PKG ERROR [package-prebuild.c/genfiles()] : Error 0 on system
(cp -d /vobs/tito/fdd/app/files/m2/launcher.11
/tmp/tmpdir_ap/ck/up/config/launcher.11)
```

On another build, I have the following error.

```
make[3]: Leaving directory
`/vobs/...............'
Failure in communication with signing server...........
failure getting the chain key file, aborting.
---
Unexpected error!
```

Answer (score 2):

Two builds running in parallel are going to run into trouble if they both require exclusive access to a resource at the same time. On big projects, it may not be immediately evident that the two builds need access to the same resource because it could be the Makefile of a third party library which uses another third party library, etc.

For instance, this error message:

```
`/tmp/tmpdir_ap/ck/up/config/launcher.11': Permission denied
```

suggest that the build uses a temporary directory located in `/tmp/` but whose name is not generated to prevent clashes. So if you have two folks running a build which uses that temporary directory, you're going to run into problems.

I don't know what is causing your network error but again if it is a matter of exclusive access (e.g. if the build process starts a server on a fixed port), then that could explain why the build fails.

The solution to this kind of conflict is to go through the build process to ensure that temporary directories are created to have unique names, ports can be assigned dynamically to avoid conflicts, etc.